# How to send Pushover in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pushover

What is the best approach to send a [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) via VBA?
In Pushover website [code example](https://pushover.net/faq#library), I didn't find a VBA example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is the Function.

PS: I use an auxiliar function to format strings

**TesteFunction:**

```
  Public Sub Test()
      Debug.Print PushOverPost("myApplication", "mySubscriptionGroup", "Hello Stackoverflow!")
  End Sub
```

**PushoverFunction:**

```
  ' Send a post via PushOver
  ' @param In application as String: The application's token
  ' @param In group as String: The user/group token
  ' @param In message as String: The message that you want to send
  ' @return as String(): The post response
  Public Function PushOverPost(ByVal application As String, ByVal group As String, ByVal message As String) As String
      Dim xhttp As Object, params As String, url As String
      Set xhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

      params = StringFormat("token={0}&user={1}&message={2}", application, group, message)
      url = "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json"

      With xhttp
          .Open "POST", url, False
          .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          .send params

          PushOverPost = .responseText
      End With
  End Function
```

**Auxiliar Function:**

```
  ' Generate a string using .NET format, i.e. {0}, {1}, {2} ...
  ' @param In strValue as String: A composite format string that includes one or more format items
  ' @param In arrParames as Variant: Zero or more objects to format.
  ' @return as String: A copy of format in which the format items have been replaced by the string representations of the corresponding arguments.
  ' @example: Debug.Print StringFormat("My name is {0} {1}. Hey!", "Mauricio", "Arieira")
  Public Function StringFormat(ByVal strValue As String, ParamArray arrParames() As Variant) As String
      Dim i As Integer

      For i = LBound(arrParames()) To UBound(arrParames())
          strValue = Replace(strValue, "{" & CStr(i) & "}", CStr(arrParames(i)))
      Next

      StringFormat = strValue
  End Function
```